# Different behavior of application while running on selenium script

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8

I am testing an application in my office environment, as it is restricted ,would not be into the situation to post any code snippet.

**Environment**:
Windows 7, IE-8.

**Description**: While executing the testing scenario manually i am able to proceed without any issue ,but doing that with selenium script, i am stuck with no solution.

**Scenario**:

1. Application launched with certificate error, which i have handled.
2. Moves to the login page and login is successful.
3. Clicks on a button ,given beside a text box.
4. which open a child window and the value to the box is to be selected a from the links displayed on child window.

**Issue faced:**

While performing the above steps , no issue is found and able to select link displayed on pop up child window.

But

a. While executing it with selenium web driver script, after Step#3, pop up child window open and **certificate error** is displayed again.

b. And after handling that error, i am not getting any links on the pop up child window, which were supposed to be there, same as they were while executed manually.

I have no idea why this is happening as this does not seem to be a issue with application.

Any help/Suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look [here](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/how-to-handle-self-signed-ssl-certificate-error-in-ie8-selenium-webdriver-ja) #region SSL workaround for IE
if (driver.GetType() == typeof(InternetExplorerDriver) && driver.Title.Contains("Certificate"))
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");

Answer (score 0):

Did you lowered all the security Level  and Privacy Level settings to low before running your script. Please check that it may cause this certificate issue.

1. Open IE
2. Click on settings icon
3. Click Internet Options
4. Move to Security Tab, inside select zone box you will have {Internet, Local Internet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites}
5. Click one by one and reduce the Security Level to Low for all the 4
6. Click Privacy tab
7. Reduce the setting to 'Low' or 'Accept All cookies'

Also Uncheck the 'Enable Protected mode' check box for all the 4 in Security tab.

Try this settings change before your script run. Hope your issue will get cleared.